# SQL Server Enterprise Manager - Mass Delete of Tables and Changing Ownership of Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2000

I have pretty much no experience with SQL Server's Enterprise Manager so I am not sure if this is even possible (or hopefully laughably simple!)

During an import into a database something has happened where each table has duplicated itself with two important differences.

The first is that the Owner on both tables is different, the second is that only the structure has copied across on one of the copies.

Sod's law indicated that of course the data was stored on the tables owned by the wrong person, so my question is can I quickly delete all tables owned by one user and can I quickly change the ownership of all other tables to bring them in line.

There are enough tables that automation is going to be my preferred option by a LONG way!

Comment: Version of SQL Server? (I'm presuming 2000 because of Enterprise Manager but just to be sure)

Comment: @Martin, yeah 2000, sorry, I will edit my post now.

Comment: Don;t forget to fix why this happened so the problem doesn't recreate itself. I write all creation scripts specifially specifying dbo as the owner (or in newer versions, the schemawe want to use for the table). All our devs are expected to do this and it is part of our code review porcess to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @emptyOwner varchar(20)
declare @wrongOwner varchar(20)
declare @emptyOwnerID bigint
declare @wrongOwnerID bigint
declare @tableName nvarchar(255)

set @emptyOwner = 'dbo'
set @wrongOwner = 'guest'

select @emptyOwnerID = (select uid from sysusers where name = @emptyOwner)
select @wrongOwnerID = (select uid from sysusers where name = @wrongOwner)

select name as tableName
into #tempTable
from systables
where type='U'
and exists (select 1 from systables where type = 'U' and uid = @emptyOwnerID)
and exists (select 1 from systables where type = 'U' and uid = @wrongOwnerID)

declare @dynSQL nvarchar(MAX)

declare ownme cursor for
  select tableName from #tempTable

open ownme
fetch next from ownme into @tableName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    @dynSQL = 'DROP TABLE [' + @emptyOwner + '].[' + @tableName + ']'
    exec(@dynSQL)

    @dynSQL = 'sp_changeobjectowner ''[' + @wrongOwner + '].[' + @tableName + ']'',''' + @emptyOwner + ''''
    exec(@dynSQL)

    fetch next from ownme into @tableName
end

close ownme
deallocate ownme
```

Comment: This would automate the whole process of selecting the duplicated tables, dropping the table that is empty, and changing ownership.  All you should need to change is the two Owner variables at the top.

Answer (score 3):

For changing ownership, see: [SQL Table Ownership Changes, Quick and Easy](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/30/SQL-Table-Ownership-Changes_2C00_-Quick-and-Easy.aspx)

The code given in the above link is:

```
DECLARE @old sysname, @new sysname, @sql varchar(1000)

SELECT
  @old = 'oldOwner_CHANGE_THIS'
  , @new = 'dbo'
  , @sql = '
  IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE
      QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+''.''+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) = ''?''
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @old + '''
  )
  EXECUTE sp_changeobjectowner ''?'', ''' + @new + ''''

EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable @sql
```

Comment: This would help with one piece of the puzzle, but it doesn't help remove the extra tables.  Also this would change ownership of all tables, not just duplicated ones (though that may be ok.)

Comment: As I mentioned (in the first 3 words of my post), this was intended to address the change of ownership portion of the question. You are correct that the bad tables should probably be dropped first.

Comment: As totally different users are in play the order isn't *that* important.